# Shell script runner and `--help` generator

Tags: shell, scripting

I've got a tree full of shell scripts for doing all sorts of things relevant to my project. I would love it if there was a tool `foo` such that I could run `foo --help` and it would print the documentation associated with each of my scripts (say, with some uniform system of annotation). Bonus points if I can then run `foo build` and it will run `scripts/build.sh`.

Googling around has turned up nothing, but maybe I haven't looked the right places. Is there any such program? It would be no problem to write, I just would be surprised if someone hasn't already.

Comment: There's things like [optparse for bash](https://github.com/nk412/optparse).

Comment: `foo() { case $1 in help) for s in scripts; do $s --help ;done;; *) scripts/$i.sh;; esac; }`

Comment: Well, I've moved to [PyInvoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/) for all my scripting needs and my life is certainly better for it.